# I'm having difficulty understanding the Shellshock vulnerability verification

Tags: linux, bash, security, shellshock-bash-bug

I got this while I was checking for the [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) vulnerability:

```
host1:~$ env x='(){ :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo hello"
hello
host1:~$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo hello"
vulnerable
hello
host1:~$
```

Weird huh?

Comment: are you running a cgi bash script ? I guess not ?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why on earth, the second statement prints "vulnerable" whilst the first one does not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bash recognizes an environment variable as a function if it starts with precisely the four characters `() {`, including the space. So `env x='(){ :;}; echo vulnerable'` doesn't count.

This doesn't quite conform to the syntax you use to define a function in `bash`; internally, `bash` will store the string representation of a function in a normalized form. If the function is exported (with `export -f function_name`), then the normalized form is added to the environment, and child `bash` processes will recognize it as a function definition.

The "shellshock" bug comes from the way `bash` handles recognized functions; the buggy versions of `bash` (which go back a long way) simply evaluate the string from the environment as a function definition (by prepending the name of the variable as the function name), which is subject to an injection attack as demonstrated in the vulnerability test.

Manually creating strings which look like `bash` function definitions in order to define functions in child `bash` processes is a known technique. Exporting functions and reimporting them is very common, and often is not even noticed by the user. (For example, this technique is used to pass bash functions into subshells started by `xargs bash -c` and `find ... -exec bash -c`.)

Comment: Interesting; I never thought to see how something like `foo () ( echo bar )` was exported; it's `foo=() { ( echo bar )`.

Comment: Yes, I saw precisely that particularity. But I'd thought that spaces wouldn't be of much use as tokenizers when you have block declarations with separators. I mean, often in bash scripts I'd have `foo()\n{ do_something }` working without any problems...

Comment: @chepner: The `{...}` are added implicitly by bash. Posix allows any compound command, but `bash` transforms all functions definitions to the brace-surrounded form.

Comment: @Marcel: you don't need to type the function definition with whitespace before the `{` (and anyway a newline is whitespace) but bash normalizes the text internally.

Comment: I was looking at the output of `env | grep foo`, which of course omitted the second line of output that included the trailing brace.

Comment: @chepner: Use a different shell. `export -f foo; dash -c 'echo $foo'`, for example.

Comment: Oh, I know. I can see the full string exported by just looking at the output of `env` without using `grep` to filter out too much :)

Answer (score 2):

`bash` is a little picky about what it considers an embedded function definition in the environment. In the first

```
env x='(){ :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo hello"}
```

the lack of a space between `()` and `{` is enough to prevent `bash` from recognizing this as an exported function, so it remains a simple shell variable; to see, try running

```
env x='(){ :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo $x'
```

In the second example, the value of `x`, *with* the space, is crafted correctly to mimic an exported function, and so the child `bash` evaluates the entire value of `x` to "import" the function, but executing the code following the function definition as well.